# use all values in a list as arguments (scheme)

Tags: list, parameters, scheme, arguments, procedure

```
    (define a_list (list 2 3 4))
    (define (add x y z)
      (+ x y z))
    (add a_list)
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but what is the correct way to do this? What I want to do is to use a random amount of variables in a list as arguments in a procedure call. The amount of variables in the list must of course match the amount of parameters the procedure has, but don't think about that, as that is not what I'm wondering about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the `apply` function is for:

```
(apply add a_list)
```